# How to Process Coordinates for OpenCV Contours?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image like here below:

[image: Braille]

With this source code, I have successfully extract the center coordinates of each dots in the image.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::Mat matSrc,matTmp,matDst;
    cv::Mat matV,matROI;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> vectorHSV;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    matSrc = cv::imread(argv[1],1);
//    matSrc = cv::imread("123.jpg",1);
//    cv::imshow("Source", matSrc);
    cv::cvtColor(matSrc,matTmp,CV_RGB2HSV);
    cv::split(matTmp,vectorHSV);
    matV = vectorHSV[2];
    matV.copyTo(matTmp);
    cv::normalize(matTmp,matTmp,0,255,CV_MINMAX,CV_8UC1);
    cv::medianBlur(matTmp,matTmp,5);
    cv::adaptiveThreshold(matTmp,matTmp,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV,125,7);
    cv::equalizeHist(matTmp,matTmp);
//    cv::erode(matTmp,matTmp,cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3,3)));
    cv::morphologyEx(matTmp,matTmp,cv::MORPH_CLOSE,cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3,3)));
    cv::Canny(matTmp,matTmp,50,150,3);
    cv::Rect ROI(0,0,matTmp.cols,matTmp.rows); 
    matROI = matTmp(ROI);
    cv::findContours(matROI,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS,cv::Point(0,0));
    std::vector<cv::Moments> muDots(contours.size());
    std::vector<cv::Point> mcDots(contours.size());
    for(size_t c=0;c < contours.size();c++)
    {
        muDots[c] = cv::moments(contours[c],false);
        mcDots[c] = cv::Point(static_cast<int>(muDots[c].m10/muDots[c].m00) , static_cast<int>(muDots[c].m01/muDots[c].m00));
    }
    for(int allDots=0;allDots < mcDots.size();allDots++)
    {
        std::cout << allDots << ": " << mcDots[allDots].x << "," << mcDots[allDots].y << std::endl;
    }

    matTmp.copyTo(matDst);
    imshow("ROI",matROI);
//    imshow("Result", matDst);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to ask is how to process the contours if it exist or not, in short description I want to do like in this algorithm:

```
for(x=0;x < Image.cols;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y < Image.rows;y++)
        {
            if(Contour coordinates at X,Y = Exist)
            {
                 vectorBraille.push_back = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                 vectorBraille.push_back = 0;
             } 
        }
    }
```

Please, I really need suggestion for this problem, I'm a little bit stuck in here.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a response map with your contours. Use `DrawContours` with hole_color=external_color>0.
Read [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) or [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html). Sample code:

```
cv::Mat responsemap = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC1);
cv::DrawContours(responsemap, contours, external_color, hole_color, max_level, 1, 8);
if (responsemap.at<uchar>(y,x)!=0) std::cout<<"contour area";
```

In case you need only the centers to be printed on the response map then set them manually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to recognize braille, right?

How about creating a mask that has the form of braille - white where there might be dots and black where you don't expect them.
Something like

```
    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1, CV:RGB(0,0,0));
    cv::Mat out = cv::Mat(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1, CV:RGB(0,0,0));
    cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(X,Y),10, CV_RGB(255,255,255),-1);
    (...)
    img.copyTo(out,mask);
```

So you create two black Mats that have the same size and type as your image (`img`), then you draw white circles on the mask, at the points where you expect the braille dots.
Finally you use cv::copyTo which takes an input Mat, an output Mat and a mask.

On this new image you run your contour detection. As a result, you only detect dots where you expect them.